# Unable to create clustered bar chart apache POI in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi, bar-chart

I'm following this link [How to generate a stacked bar chart or column chart in Excel using Apache POI](https://roytuts.com/how-to-generate-stacked-bar-chart-or-column-chart-in-excel-using-apache-poi/) to create a clustered bar chart side by side using the Apache POI library.

Everything was perfect but then I realize that the output bar chart is eliminating data for the first and last columns.

Also, how do I change the colors for the bars being displayed? I only changed this line to CLUSTERED from STACKED.

```
bar.setBarGrouping(BarGrouping.CLUSTERED);
```

This is the output bar chart:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need set `AxisCrossBetween`, so the left axis crosses the category axis between the categories. Else first and last category is exactly on cross points and the bars are only half visible.

So for your example you need additional:

```
...
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisCrossBetween;
...
```

and then

```
...
XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
leftAxis.setTitle("Area & Population");
leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);
...
```

For setting the colors see [BarChart
example from apache poi](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/usermodel/BarChart.java).

Comment: It worked, Thanks a lot, Axel. Sry I dont have much reputation to upvote your answer.